# Widget Logic - display on page and all child

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, logic

I have problem with condition function in Widget Logic (worpdress).
I would like to display menu on subpage and all child set to it.

I use this:

```
global $post; return (in_array(1959,get_post_ancestors($post)));
```

In this case it works on all child but no dispaly on subpage (1959).

I try also:

```
global $post; return (is_page('Offer') || ($post->post_parent=="1959"));
```

In this case it doesn't display on deeper child.

Comment: Please share more codes. And check `wp-content/debug.txt`, let me see what you see there.

Comment: That's the whole code. I don't have file debug.txt. The simple codes you can see at https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-logic/other_notes/

Comment: It is a plugin specific question. We do not know how the plugin author did code it. So, please follow their documentation.

Comment: Ok but it is based on wordpress conditional tags function. I follow WP documentation but it does't work.

Answer (score 1):

I see you've already found a solution to your question however I'd like to go over the details of why your original attempts didn't work and how the code could be improved.

Your first snippet is going to retrieve all ancestor pages of the page (post object) provided. If any of those ancestors match the page ID you've defined, it will return true. The current page isn't being tested so if you're on the page you're checking for it will still return false.

In your second attempt, you're checking the `post_parent` property which is only giving you the immediate parent ID. Any higher level pages aren't included.

My solution would be:

```
global $post;
$page_id = 1959; // the page ID you want to test against.

return ( is_page( $page_id ) || in_array( $page_id, get_post_ancestors( $post ) ) );
```

I'm checking `is_page()` first in an attempt to avoid running the more intensive `get_post_ancestors()` function. I'm also using a variable for the page ID which is passed into both tests avoiding confusion.

You could transform the code into a function to make it reusable.

```
function wpse_is_page_or_subpage( $page_id ) {
    global $post;
    return ( is_page( $page_id ) || in_array( $page_id, get_post_ancestors( $post ) ) );
}
```

Usage: `wpse_is_page_or_subpage( 1959 );`

Answer (score 0):

I resloved it by this:

```
global $post; return (in_array(1959,get_post_ancestors($post))) || (is_page('Offer'));
```